# Regexp to extract a class name from a file path

Tags: regex

Let's say I have:

```
D:\workspace\src\com\package\MYCLASS.java
```

How do I write a regexp to extract only "MYCLASS" ?

Comment: Any specific programming language?

Comment: @Artur does it matter? He just wants a regex pattern I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the language you are working with supports  working with paths use it. Like `os.path.split*` in Python.

The regular expression can be `([\w-]+)\.`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

**PATTERN**

```
(?<=\\)[^\s\\]+?(?=\.java)
```

**INPUT**

```
D:\workspace\src\com\package\MYCLASS.java
```

**OUTPUT**

```
MYCLASS
```

Answer (score 0):

`\\([^\\]+)\.java` should do it, although you may need to fiddle with the capture - right now it will match anything in between \ and .java.

Note too that you'd need to extract the captured group (index 0).

If the language you're using supports [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), `(?<=\\)[^\\]+(?=\.java)` will also match *without* using captures.

Comment: this is perfect, but I'm using ANT, and lookarounds are not supported.

Comment: Right, then the first one is probably the best you're gonna get.